# host java website in Windows machine

Tags: java, web-services

Anybody knows why **godaddy.com** cannot host **Java** based **website** in **Windows** machine? Is there any technical difficulty to do so?

**EDIT:**

this link has answer and solution: http://www.oreillynet.com/onjava/blog/2006/09/why_is_javaenabled_hosting_so_1.html

Comment: THey just dont o it. Like no java host installed. Uses reosoruces they dont want you to waste 8java is not too leightweight). Their business decision purely. Have fun finding a budget java host.

Comment: So this is a sign showing Java is NOT one of the best tech for web application?

Comment: It is not generally a problem for enterprise applications, this is where Java found its home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To host a Java-based website (I guess you mean JSP or similar), then you need a Java application server, e.g. [Apache Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat).

There is no technical reason why a Java application server cannot run on Windows. There are commercial reasons why web hosting providers generally do not offer, or charge more for, Java hosting versus more "standard" configurations based on [Apache httpd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) or Windows [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services).

Comment: what do you mean by commercial reasons? If you own the copy of your windows, what else do they care about? Are there any licensing issues?

Comment: It is not licensing. Try Google for "Why is java hosting expensive".

Comment: why Java community doesn't do something to make Apache support Java based website directly without the extra Tomcat?

Comment: Would not really change the higher memory usage, you know. Tomcat itself is not the issue - more the fact that the rest still uses a lot more than for example .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Is your hosting option from GoDaddy for a Linux based host or a full Linux virtual machine?

The problem is likely that you have a Linux based host where you have your own chroot to isolate your files and data from other customers and your pages are served with their webserver.

What you would need to find is a hosting plan which includes a Java server, like Glassfish or Websphere. You could also find a host where you get an entire Linux virtual machine that you can install your own software on and run your own webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please identify what the problem is? You are asking why Godaddy.com does not offer Java web application hosting on Windows. This is a strategic decision by Godaddy.com, there is no technical reason behind it. Your question is like asking why Ford does not offer pink as a stock color on their cars.

If you are looking for an alternative hosting provider who offers Java web application hosting, you should ask a new question stating exactly that.